# Django users groups

Tags: django, usergroups

Authenticated users can add groups (if have permissions), add users (users added in groups that he create) and add permissions for groups or users.

What is the best way to solve that task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although django's user/group models aren't set up in such a way as to restrict users so that they can only modify users/groups that they create, it is possible to implement.

[Here is a django snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1054/) which provides an example of object level permissions.

Perhaps you could elaborate on the problem you are attempting to solve.